# Page keeps refreshing on submit

Tags: php, pageload, page-refresh

I have did a review monitor system, allowing admins to approve, unapproved or delete comments. The graphical interface shows a table with the user's review, date, the status and commands such as approved, unapproved and delete. The status is set by default to unapproved until the approved link is clicked on. Each command is a link so whatever link is clicked it will execute and the status column in the database will change to approved or unapproved and sames goes with delete link it deletes the database row. The execution is not my problem. The problem is that the page refreshes when the commands are clicked on, and it takes two refreshes before the status has changed and shown to the admin user.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Hey Andy Homes, i have not tried that yet.

Comment: Show us your code, please.

Comment: It would get around your submission errors as it happens behind the scenes. Worth looking into

Comment: Cheers, Andy Holmes. I was thinking Ajax but just wanted a second opinion.